# Java Loop help, how to write a loop

Tags: loops

Need to write a loop that prompts the user to enter a value greater than one print the numbers from 1 to the number the user gives you inclusive (i.e., if the user enters 5 your program will print “1 2 3 4 5”).

I got the loop to print out numbers from 1-10 using the code:

```
public class Loop {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      int num = 0;

      while(num < 10) {
         num = num + 1;
         System.out.print(" " + num);
      }
   }
}
```

To complete the code I was thinking modify it to:

```
public class Loop {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      int num = 2;
      if(num <1){
         System.out.print(" Num has to be greater than one");

      while(num < 10) {
         num = num - 1;// subtract instead of add
         System.out.print(" " + num);
      }
   }
}
```

But when i compile and execute it doesn't include the 2 and also include negative numbers. How would I get it to include the entered num and stop at zero

UPDATE - got the code runnning correctly and have moved onto my next step. Which is declaring a start and stop variable and printing out the start and stop varibles with values in between. 
i.e (start < stop)if start = 1 and stop = 3 then the output is " 1 2 3 "
I have that part running but now I need to swap start and stop so that if (start>stop) it will swap the values and print out the correct output.
i.e (start>stop) start = 3, stop = 1 then out should still be " 1 2 3 " by swapping values of start and stop

here is my code so far:

```
System.out.println("\n");
int start = 1;
int stop = 5;

while(start <= stop){
   System.out.print(start + " ");
   start++;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to swap start and stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `number` is `2` , The loop goes for ever since `2<10,1<10,0<10,-1<10,-2<10....`

You are checking if the number is `less than 10` , You should also check if it is `greater than or equal to zero`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    // int num = s.nextInt();

    int num = 2;
    if (num < 1)
      System.out.print(" Num has to be greater than one");
    else
      while (num >= 0 && num < 10) {
        System.out.print(num-- + " ");
      }
  }
```

*Uncomment to read input from user*

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop from one to the specified number, so introduce a new variable that counts up from one to num.

Replace the while loop for example with:

```
for (int i=1; i<num; ++i) {
    System.out.print("  "+i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate your number before printing

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//this alows you to enter your number on keyboard and validates it (>0)
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = 0;
While (num <=0)
{
system.out.println("Enter a number greater then 0");
num = sc.nextInt();

}

for (int i=1;i<=num;i++){
system.out.println(" "+i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You decrement "num" before you print it. So your first time in the loop by the time you hit the print statement num is 1. You either need to do an increment before you enter the loop: Add 1 to num so that it will get decremented to 2 when you first print, or you need to swap the decrement and the print statements so that it prints num before you modify it. This second one you would have to account for the excess decrement so that prints 0 at the end.

Either way you are looking to decrement in your modification so you will need to check that num is 0 or greater in your while statement. This might be a situation where a for loop would be beneficial.

A good trick for you would be to step through your logic by hand recording what value each variable is after every step.

Comment: very helpful, check out my edit on my question (UPDATE--) need some help swapping values

Comment: I never noticed this response.. I really don't understand your update? You either want something akin to int start=1; int stop = 3;while(start <= stop){sysout(start); start++} like you have or going from 3 to 1 you would have int start=3; int stop = 1;while(start >= stop){sysout(start); start--}. I wouldn't try to start from the "stop" variable and go to "start"..

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = start; i <= stop; ++i)
    system.out.println(i + " ");
```